# How can i reduce the size of linux kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, resize-image

Hi friends i have installed linux kernel 3.16.3 version and kernel image found in "/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.3" size 5.9 mb it is possible to reduce the size of my current kerenl to 2 mb or less??

I have read this article : http://swift.siphos.be/linux_sea/kernelbuilding.html

But is there any straight forward way to do this?? Please help me out in this

Thank you!

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540958/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps

- Do "make menuconfig" and disable all unused features
- Inline functions increase the code size by copying the same code in multiple places.

  - Remove "inline" flag to as many functions as possible.
- Go to linker file and see any extra unused memory is allocated and remove them
  (vmlinux.lds.S in Arm codebase)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make modules as much as you can, instead of compiling the drivers as built-in. Also disable all the features that you don't need. If you know exactly the list of devices present in your hardware, then you can optimize properly your kernel configuration.

Comment: is there any short method something like; intelligently setting configuration files?

Comment: unfortunately not. It depends on your hardware running the kernel and the kernel feature mandatory for you.